# Bus clock and prescaler of an ADC

Tags: adc, clock, clock-speed

According to my text book "A clock pre-scaler is needed for ATD module's internal cock (2 MHz conversion clock) to be configured to within the specified frequency range (500 kHz to 2 MHz) for different MCU bus clock frequencies.

For maximum accuracy, selecting the 500-kHz clock is recommended where conversion and sample times are not critical. The bus clock is divided by a programmable prescaler value (2, 4, 6, . . . , 64) to generate the ATD clock."

So the questions are:

1- What is exactly MCU bus clock frequencies and why ATD module clock is dependent on it?

2- What exactly does it mean 
"For maximum accuracy, selecting the 500-kHz clock is recommended where conversion and sample times are not critical.".......How would decreasing the clock frequency can add to accuracy?

3- I have no idea what this menas "The bus clock is divided by a programmable prescaler value (2, 4, 6, . . . , 64) to generate the ATD clock."

Comment: what is ATD? is it a microprocessor? Ah, just twigged you mean A2D!

Comment: The ADC module is inside a microprocessor MCU, That microprocessor has a clock - the 'bus clock' probably many MHz - that clock is fed to the pre-scaler and has to be divided down into a rate suitable for driving the ADC. You will have to look at your system design and MCU datasheet to determine what frequency has been used for your system.

Comment: In the book it is written as ATD. It is a HCS12 microcontroller with a 10 bit, 8 channel, 2 MHZ conversion clock.

Comment: @IChodera So the 'bus clock' is the microprocessor clock which is fed to the clock prescaler?

Comment: yes. The clock pre-scaler can then divide that frequency by 2, 4, 8 etc as you select before passing on to the A2D. - never seen it called ATD before :-)

Comment: It is a text book for school, so ATD should be right!

Comment: Could you help me to understand "For maximum accuracy, selecting the 500-kHz clock is recommended where conversion and sample times are not critical"

Comment: and please type your comments as an answer so I could accept it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes. fair cop, just looked up the HCS12 datasheet, and that's what they call it! ADC is more common in other datasheets though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The MCU bus clock dictates how fast it can access memories and peripherals, and it is related to its master clock and instruction rate. You may find it specified that for a bus clock rate of 4 MHz you need a master clock or crystal oscillator running at 16 MHz : thus bus clock = master clock/4. The divisor varies between CPUs.

For a RISC processor, sometimes the instruction rate is the same as the bus clock rate (with extra cycles for loads and stores). For other CPUs you may find each instruction takes a different number of bus clock cycles, e.g. 2 for simple instructions, 3 or 4 for more complex ones.

2) Remember that each ADC clock performs one bit of an ADC conversion, typically by subtracting one voltage from another, and comparing the result? This is an analog process, and allowing the analog circuitry longer to settle before making the comparison will often reduce measurement errors, thus increasing accuracy. But the conversion obviously takes longer... You get to choose whether a faster result or a more accurate one is more important to you.

3) Compare the bus clock speed with your chosen ADC speed. If your bus clock is 4MHz (above) and you want a 1 MHz ADC clock, you need to divide the bus clock by 4 to feed the ADC. Then you would write 4 into the prescaler register (or whatever code the book tells you will make it divide by 4).

Answer (score 1):

The ADC module is inside a microprocessor (MCU), That microprocessor has a clock - the 'bus clock' probably many MHz - that clock is fed to the pre-scaler and has to be divided down into a rate suitable for driving the ADC. You have the choice of dividing the MCU clock by 2, 4, 8 etc

You will have to look at your system design and MCU datasheet to determine what frequency has been used for your system.

The clock frequency will affect the conversion time of the A2D. A2D's are fairly slow devices (compared to microprocessors) because they rely on analogue circuitry which has to settle. The optimum clock frequency for the A2D in your case for best accuracy is 500kHz, but if you need faster, less accurate answers, you could clock the ADC at up to 2MHz - remember it will take at least 10 and probably more clock cycles per conversion.